# Weird behaviour of multiple transparent Raster3D objects in one Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, opacity

Consider this code

```
$data = With[{step = .1, r = 2}, 
   Table[Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z}]^2], {x, -r, r, step}, {y, -r, r, 
     step}, {z, -r, r, step}]];

Graphics3D[{Raster3D[$data, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Red] &)], 
  Raster3D[$data, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#, Red] &)]}]
```

The generated figure looks like

[image]

Obviously the transparency works within one `Raster3D` object but not between them.

1. Is this an expected behaviour?
2. How could I go around this, assuming I cannot generate everything in one `Raster3D` object? I want to be able to patch various `Raster3D` objects according to my liking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the rendering engine to BSPTree seems to help for me:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

[image]

Not sure if this is the best solution, but do try it out.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks

Comment: I think this is because with the "^2" the values on the edge of the bounding box are still not zero, especially in the cube face centers. Try it with e.g. Exp[-Norm[{x, y, z}]^3.0] (which makes the spheres not touch the boundary).

Comment: I've realized that before and deleted my comment, probably while you were writing the reply, sorry about that

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Could you comment about this option? When should/could be tried?

Comment: Note that `Style[graphics, RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]` also works without making a persistent change to the `$FrontEnd`.  (I assume `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]` would work, too.)

Comment: @belisarius I understand this switches from default hardware rendering to software rendering, whose behaviour is more predictable I guess. But it is considerably slower. There is also the "Software" option, which seems even slower.