# How to use Glow in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, color

I get the output that I need from

```
r = 100000000000;
ParametricPlot3D[r {Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Glow[GrayLevel[z]]],
  Lighting -> None, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None]
```

However if `r = 1`, then the sphere goes black.
Why does it do that, and how to get the correct color despite `r = 1`?

Output in V11.3 on windows with Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500:
[image]
I think it's a bug now, I tried V11.2 and it worked.

Comment: Hm, looks normal on my computer. What about values of `r` in between?

Comment: @GregoryRut Fewer zeros than `r = 10000000000;` makes it black. Do you use V11.3 on windows?

Comment: 11.1.1 on Ubuntu. Have you tried to reset your kernel? Seems like there is a hidden constant that might affect your result.

Comment: @GregoryRut Yes it's restarted, but now I tried also V11.2 and got the correct output

Comment: Same black sphere on OSX with 11.3

Comment: No bug on 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On MacOS 10.13.6 and Mathematica 11.3, I also observed this issue. I was able to fix it by going to the advanced options (Preferences), and setting

> "3DRenderingMethod" $\rightarrow$ "BSPTree"

You can find this option by entering it in the search field.

I do think this should be tagged as a bug.

See also [Weird behaviour of multiple transparent Raster3D objects in one Graphics3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88520/245)